# getTimeinMillis giving a negative value

Tags: java, android

This is my date

```
Thu Feb 20 18:34:00 GMT+5:30 2014
```

When I use getTimeInMillis() I'm geting a negative value(-5856679776000). It should be something positive. Can anyone tell me why?

The stored date i.e cal1 is giving a negative value while the second date i.e current date is a positive one.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",java.util.Locale.getDefault());
try {
    java.util.Date d = format.parse(date+" "+time);
    GregorianCalendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar(d.getYear(), 
                                                   d.getMonth(), 
                                                   d.getDay(), 
                                                   d.getHours(), 
                                                   d.getMinutes());

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    GregorianCalendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
                                                   cal.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                                                   cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),
                                                   cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                                                   cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        "Stored date " + d +
        "\nCurrent date " + cal.getTime() +
        "\nStored date in ms :" + cal1.getTimeInMillis() +
        "\nCurrent time in ms :" + cal2.getTimeInMillis()+
        "\nDifference " + ((cal1.getTimeInMillis()-cal2.getTimeInMillis())/1000), 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
catch(Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Date parsing error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: What are `date` and `time` in `date + " " + time`?

Comment: what is the value of `time` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace

```
new GregorianCalendar(d.getYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay(), d.getHours(), d.getMinutes());
```

with

```
new GregorianCalendar(1900+d.getYear(), d.getMonth(), d.getDay(), d.getHours(), d.getMinutes());
```

Check the documentation of getYear method. It returns years after 1900 ... And the second cause has been already identified by @Pakspul ..

Answer (score 3):

You should swap cal1 and cal2 in your millisecond calculation. For example:

```
startdate = 12:00
enddate = 12:01

diff = enddate - startdate; // result is 1 minute
diff = startdate - enddate; // result is -1 minute
```

Comment: instead of `replace` word `swap` is better in this case,

Comment: cal1.getTimeInMillis() is itself coming negative and because of it the difference as well

Answer (score 0):

What you is doing here is that you are calling cal2 after cal1 so it will have definatly higher value than cal1 because it has the mostrecent time, hence the negative result value.

just switch them and try again like this:

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Stored date "+d+"\nCurrent date "+cal.getTime()+"\nStored date in ms :"+cal1.getTimeInMillis()+"\nCurrent time in ms :"+cal2.getTimeInMillis()+"\nDifference "+((cal2.getTimeInMillis()-cal1.getTimeInMillis())/1000), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```